# Determining the unique non-abelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra using structure constants

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\{x,y\}$ be a basis for a Lie algebra $L$. Since $[x,x]=0$ and $[y,y]=0$, all products in $L$ yield scalar multiples of $[x,y]$. Let us define a new basis, letting $[x,y]$ be our first basis element and $z$ any vector in $L$ linearly independent of $[x,y]$.

**Then $[[x,y],z]=a[x,y]$ for some scalar $a$.**

I'm trying to understand this surely simple thing. I mean, we have $[[x,y],z]=a[x,y]+bz$ because $\{[x,y],z\}$ is a basis. How do I show that $b=0$ here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

$[x,y]=ax+by$ implies that $[x,[x,y]]=b[x,y]$ and $[y,[x,y]]=-a[x,y]$.

Write $z=ux+vy$, $[[x,y],z]=[[x,y],ux+vy]=-u[x,[x,y]]-v[y,[x,y]]=(-ub+va)[x,y]$.

Answer (score 2):

You say yourself, "all products in $L$ yield scalar multiples of $[x,y]$".

Yes. *All* products do. And what you are looking at there is a product.